# Detect a Tap on an Already Activated UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITextField and it is activated (the caret is blinking).  I want to detect when the user taps the UITextField (where default behavior is to show/hide the "Select/SelectAll/Paste" context menu).  I've tried several things, one of which was a UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
tap.delegate = self;
```

Simply tapping the UITextField produces no call to my handler.

```
- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    if (tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        // do something
    }

    if (tap.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

"Swiping" the UITextField produces the call (which doesn't solve the problem), and even so, tap.state is always UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded (I would like to be able to differentiate between the TouchDown and the TouchUp).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a transparent view (or 99% transparent) overlaid on the text field, and put the gesture recognizer in that view?

Insert the view when the user activates it, and remove it when the text view is dismissed.

As I recall you may need to use a transparency of alpha = 0.999;, as I seem to recall completely transparent views won't have their gesture recognizers activated (but I could be wrong, or my info out of date.)